# After moving files/directories, GitHub shows no history for the files but Git does - is this due to how I moved them?

Tags: git, github

We have a repo where we had a directory structure like:

```
/database-stuff
/main-project
/main-project/src/somefile.java
...elided...
```

We then moved the files to be like:

```
/database-stuff
/src/somefile.java
...elided...
```

After doing this and pushing the changes, on GitHub, when i view "history" for any of the files, it shows only today.

However, when I'm in IntelliJ and choose `git->Show History` on any file, it shows all their history (back to last year).

Is there a way to fix this? Do i need to move/commit file moves in a special way for git/GitHub to see them with full history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, IntelliJ will show the full history (`git log --follow`) which follows file moves (even though the [graphic version of that log is still buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27798115/6309))

However, GitHub cannot do the same (for performance reason), and only shows the history for file without their prior location history.